# Debugger doesn't stop when using docker

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop

Whenever I am adding a debugger in my code every time to reflect the changes I need to restart the container which is time-consuming. It used to work a month back when I haven't updated the Docker desktop and was using a very old version of the Docker desktop. Can someone help me with this issue? Let me know if any other information is required

I do have the following configuration in my docker-compose

```
stdin_open: true
tty: true
```

From the code side, I am using the gem 'pry' in the Gemfile

**Edit 1 Added Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml**

**docker-compose**

```
version: '3'
networks:
  development:
  test:
volumes:
  gem_cache:
  shared_data:
  mysql_db_data:
  shared_mysql_data:
services:
  be_db_mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: be_db_mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mysql_db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - shared_mysql_data:/var/mysql_shared
    networks:
      - development
      - test
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass@123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: be_dev
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'test@123'
      SHELL: /bin/bash
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  be_app:
    build:
      context: ./be
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    image: be/app
    container_name: be_app
    volumes:
      - ./storage:/mnt/storage
      - ./be:/home/app/be
      - shared_data:/var/shared
      - gem_cache:/usr/local/bundle/gems
    networks:
      - development
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    entrypoint: dev-entrypoint.sh
    command: ['puma', '-C', 'config/puma.rb']
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
    depends_on:
      - be_db_mysql
```

**Dockerfile** Please note I haven't made any changes in the docker file in the last few months. So, I don't suspect it is the issue from the dockerfile

```
FROM phusion/passenger-ruby25:1.0.10

ENV APP_PATH /home/app/be
ENV BUNDLE_VERSION 1.17.3
ENV BUNDLE_PATH /usr/local/bundle/gems
ENV TMP_PATH /tmp/
ENV RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT true
ENV RAILS_PORT 3000

# copy entrypoint scripts and grant execution permissions
COPY ./docker-resources/dev-docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/dev-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dev-entrypoint.sh

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get remove -y libmysqlclient-dev libmysqlclient20 && \
    apt-get install -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" wget  nano tzdata make cmake g++ swig nginx-extras libxext6 libxrender1 imagemagick libmariadbclient-dev shared-mime-info && \
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*


RUN mkdir -p $APP_PATH $BUNDLE_PATH && \
    mkdir -p /mnt/storage/static /mnt/storage/uploads /mnt/pdf && chown -R app:app /mnt/storage /mnt/pdf $APP_PATH $BUNDLE_PATH

RUN gem install bundler --version "$BUNDLE_VERSION" \
    && rm -rf $GEM_HOME/cache/*
RUN bundle config --global gems.contribsys.com 1234:4567 && bundle config --global silence_root_warning 1
RUN chown -R app:app /run

USER app

WORKDIR $APP_PATH

EXPOSE $RAILS_PORT
ENTRYPOINT [ "bundle", "exec" ]
```

To start the application I use the following command

**docker-compose up**

**My configuration**
Windows 10
Windows Terminal
Docker Desktop version - 4.19.0
Rails - 5.2.8.1
ruby - 2.5.8

Comment: Update the question with relevant info: `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose` file, the source code tree, and the docker commands you use.

Comment: @Max Done let me know if you need more information